# How Do I add or insert additional rows and elements to a Pandas Dataframe Dataset?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, insert, row, multiple-columns

I'm having issues inserting extra rows to the dataframe seen below. The dataset has two columns as seen below. The plan is to add some missing time (10:03:00, 10:05:00, 10:07:00....) in between the rows and make the column elements all zero for the added rows.

```
               Time   Z(dB)
```

0   1900-01-01 10:02:00   0.000
1   1900-01-01 10:04:00   0.000
2   1900-01-01 10:06:00   0.000
3   1900-01-01 10:08:00   0.000
4   1900-01-01 10:10:00   0.000
5   1900-01-01 10:12:00   0.000
6   1900-01-01 10:14:00   0.000
7   1900-01-01 10:16:00   0.000
8   1900-01-01 10:18:00   0.000
9   1900-01-01 10:20:00   0.000
10  1900-01-01 10:22:00   0.000
11  1900-01-01 10:24:00   0.000
12  1900-01-01 10:26:00   0.000
13  1900-01-01 10:28:00   0.000
14  1900-01-01 10:30:00   0.000
15  1900-01-01 10:32:00   0.000

```
#"df" DataFrame, inserting rows for a range of date
dt =pd.date_range('1900-01-01 10:01:00','1900-01-01 00:00:00')
idx=pd.DatetimeIndex(dt)
df=df.reindex(idx)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new index using date_range with 1 min frequency and reindex:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [ ["1900-01-01 10:02:00", 0.000],
         ["1900-01-01 10:04:00", 0.000], 
         ["1900-01-01 10:06:00", 0.000], 
         ["1900-01-01 10:08:00", 0.000], 
         ["1900-01-01 10:10:00", 0.000], 
         ["1900-01-01 10:12:00", 0.000], 
         ["1900-01-01 10:14:00", 0.000], 
         ["1900-01-01 10:16:00", 0.000], 
         ["1900-01-01 10:18:00", 0.000],
         ["1900-01-01 10:20:00", 0.000], 
         ["1900-01-01 10:22:00", 0.000], 
         ["1900-01-01 10:24:00", 0.000], 
         ["1900-01-01 10:26:00", 0.000], 
         ["1900-01-01 10:28:00", 0.000], 
         ["1900-01-01 10:30:00", 0.000], 
         ["1900-01-01 10:32:00", 0.000]]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=data, columns=["Time", "Z(dB)"])
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"])
df = df.set_index("Time")

idx = pd.date_range("1900-01-01 10:02", "1900-01-01 10:32", freq="1min")
df = df.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)

# print(df.head())
# 1900-01-01 10:02:00    0.0
# 1900-01-01 10:03:00    0.0
# 1900-01-01 10:04:00    0.0
# 1900-01-01 10:05:00    0.0
# 1900-01-01 10:06:00    0.0
```

Comment: Thank you. How do I include the added rows (with zero values) to only the first 100 indices in the dataframe while the rest of the the data is left unchanged, with a frequency of 2 mins.